# What is a good and free static apex code review plugin for IDEA, eclipse and ANT?

Tags: apex, visualforce, bestpractice, ant, ci

Java has a number of useful and FREE tools for reviewing not just formatting and style but quality of code and bad coding habits.

[Checkmarx](https://checkmarx.com/why-checkmarx/languages/#) and [Code scan](http://codescan.villagechief.com/eclipse/) could work but they are not free and open source.

[Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/) works well for java but there are no official updates to support Apex.

What does static code analysis for apex that is free?

Comment: What's wrong with Checkmarx? Can you be more specific in your criteria? Because in my experience that code does seem to fulfill your needs.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Sorry for the confusion all. I updated the question to be more specific. I'm looking for open source / free static code analysis for apex. Currently the working solutions are paid. Will you consider this for reopen?

Comment: Checkmarx *is* free. I guess the open source part is a legitimate gripe, but I doubt you will find open source options.

Comment: Is it really? That would be terrific. Though I only see the free trial option on the website.

Comment: I wouldn't call Checkmarx a real static code analyzer for Apex.  It only analyzes permission based (security) problems and was solely used to check code for the Salesforce Security Review in the past. You can check for naming, complexity, bug risk things there like you would expect from such a tool.

Answer (score 8):

We recently ported the [famous Java Static code analyzer **PMD**](https://pmd.github.io/) to Apex. We also [ported many of the original Java rules](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.0/pmd-apex/rules/index.html) and created a few Apex specific to showcase how to write language-specific rules (e.g. AvoidSoqlInLoops, AvoidLogicInTriggers,...).

Other than CodeScan, our effort is open source and was merged back into the original PMD repository on Github (https://github.com/pmd/pmd). Every Salesforce developer or expert out there can fork the repo and create new and better rules and integrations.

As the Apex language module is now part of the regular PMD distribution [all PMD-based tools](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/integrations.html) also speak Apex now, e.g. the **Eclipse / Force.com IDE**.

[image]

We have also built an [open-source engine](https://github.com/Up2Go/codeclimate-apexmetrics) for **[CodeClimate](https://codeclimate.com/engines)** so you cannot only analyze files on your local machine but also have code checked into your Github repos verified.

[image]